# Curl, git, other commands hang while trying to download file

Tags: networking, 18.04, curl

Currently on Ubuntu 18.04.12, when I try to download something from the terminal, or push to git or any similar command it always hangs on the download either indefinitely or for a very long time. However when I Ctrl+C and try again it usually works after a couple of tries.

I was able to diagnose a bit and the hanging happens when curl tries to resolve the ipv6 address of the server instead of the ipv4. Problem is, I don't have ipv6 configured or an ipv6 DNS server setup for that matter, so I'm really lost why it would try that (or at least why it would try that so many times and not revert back to ipv4). I disabled ipv6 with sysctl but it doesn't make a difference.

I'm a bit lost here since this doesn't seem to happen on other machines in the same network, but I believe this one is the only one with Ubuntu 18.

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you edit the question and add contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`  and `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @user.dz Done, I haven't really modified them.

Comment: It seems ok, let's different resolver. install `libnss-resolve` then modify this line `hosts:          files dns` in  `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to `hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns` , `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved` , 
`sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved` , may be  a reboot is required.

Comment: I'm honestly not a fan of installing another resolver, they can be very finicky to get back in order afterwards and I cannot afford to reformat the machine. Is there anything else I could do?